# How can I highlight, not select, text in a data bound WPF TextBox or RichTextBox?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, binding, richtextbox

**Some context:**
I'm trying to highlight all occurrences of some searched text in a data bound TextBox or a RichTextBox.

**What I have found until now:**
I figured out how to highlight text in a RichTextBox:

```
    <RichTextBox>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run>In this</Run>
                <Run Background="Yellow">example</Run>
                <Run>the word</Run>
                <Run Background="Yellow">example</Run>
                <Run>is highlighted.</Run>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

**Question:**
How can I, for example, by using some IValueConverter, bind this RichTextBox so that all occurrences of the expression "example" are highlighted?

Comment: What is the type the property you want to bind to?  A FlowDocument or a string?

Comment: A simple string for now although I'd be interested to see how one would do it for a non-flat document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     string example = "example";
     string exampleDoc = "hello, example, hello example.";
     FlowDocument doc =
        new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("hello, example, hello example.")));
     int pos = 0;
     while (0 <= (pos = exampleDoc.IndexOf(example)))
     {
        new Bold(doc.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(pos),
                 doc.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(pos + example.Length));
     }
```

This will get you started.  It would be easy to put this in a ValueConverter from string to FlowDocument with a ConverterParameter of the word you want to highlight.  Watch out for the TextPointer changing as you add more formats, you'll see the highlighting shift to the left.  I'm sure you'll figure out the best way to handle this in your situation.

Comment: Thanks, but:
- What property of RichTextBox can I bind to?
- Your loop is broken
- The part where I actually change properties of the text is the easy part - what I'm trying to get a "start" with  is how to bind to apply the transformation on the text - and back.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I forgot, you can't do it directly.  Check out this codeproject sample.  It might help.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BindableWPFRichTextBox.aspx